# Start Menu Folder as a Subdirectory - Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I want to add a shortcut to my program in the start menu as follows:

```
MyAppPublisher\MyAppName\MyAppName
```

I have this in my script:

```
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppPublisher}
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
```

But the start menu folder is always:

```
MyAppName\MyAppName
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The behavior you've described is strange. Your current script must have created `MyAppPublisher\MyAppName`, not `MyAppName\MyAppName` shortcut. Make sure you're running the correct setup (if you are having more than one InnoSetup IDE opened e.g.) and that you've properly re-compiled the script before running the setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as easy as specifying this path in the `Name` parameter of the entry in the [`[Icons]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_iconssection.htm) section. Your current script creates a shortcut like `MyAppPublisher\MyAppName`, this one will do what you need:

```
#define MyAppName "MyAppName"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"
#define MyAppPublisher "MyAppPublisher"

[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppPublisher}
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "{#MyAppExeName}"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
; notice the full path to the created shortcut, {group} is taken from the Select
; Start Menu Folder page edit box (if shown), which is by default taken from the
; DefaultGroupName directive value; this start menu folder path is then followed
; by the tail of the shortcut path
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
```

Comment: Note that it's best practice to specify the "Full" path in the default and just use `{group}` as normal. This will then allow the user to put them in whichever group they want.

Comment: It depends on what OP actually wants to allow users to choose. If just the start menu folder (and the rest remain constant as `{#MyAppName}`), then this is the right way. [+1 for your alternative]

Comment: Note that enforcing a subfolder structure like this will annoy some users.  As Deanna said, best practice is to allow the user to change all of the path, and only install simple icons under that rather than subfolders.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the group to be in a subfolder, you need to specify the sub folder.

The best way to do this is to append it to the end of the `DefaultGroupName` directive which will show the correct info in the setup wizard and allow the user to change it to as single folder or another location entirely if they wish.

```
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}
```

Note that the Start Menu in Windows 8 is not heirachical so any nesting won't be seen anyway.

Comment: Seems the same in Windows 10 - it just completely ignores subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, my script suggested in the question was correct, for some reason I needed to generate a new GUID for the script for the changes to take effect

Comment: No, it is not correct. You've asked how to create a shortcut in `MyAppPublisher\MyAppName\MyAppName` and that can't simply happen with the script from your question. You are missing the last `\MyAppName` there.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Although I still need to change my GUID to make it happen for some reason. Weird.

Comment: I'd say, it should be enough to uninstall the last version you've installed during your tests.

Comment: ^ As TLama said, you need to uninstall before testing changes to the installer.  By default Inno will remember the paths chosen during the previous install and default to those, even if you change your script.  (And this is what users expect, so it's a good thing.)