# Cannot get [Icons] Name parameter to recognize name set in [Setup] section

Tags: inno-setup

I've looked through the other icons/stackoverflow posts, and I feel like I'm doing things correctly, yet I get the following error:

```
Compiler engine version: Inno Setup 5.5.5 (a)

[ISPP] Preprocessing.
Error on line 30 in <stdin>: Column 42:
[ISPP] Undeclared identifier: "DefaultGroupName".
Compile aborted.
gmake: *** [Makefile:139: releaseapp] Error 2

[Setup]
AppName=SimModeler
AppVerName=SimModeler __BUILD__
AppVersion=__BUILD__
AppPublisher=Simmetrix Inc.
DefaultDirName={pf}\SimModeler 7.0-__BUILD__
DefaultGroupName=SimModeler 7.0-__BUILD__
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
SourceDir=__SOURCE_DIR__
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

[Files]
Source: "*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\SimModeler 7.0"; Filename: "{app}\simmodeler.bat" ; Comment: "SimModeler"; WorkingDir: "{userdocs}"; IconFilename: "{app}\simmetrix.ico"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#DefaultGroupName}"; Filename: "{app}\simmodeler.bat" ; Comment: "SimModeler"; WorkingDir: "{userdocs}"; IconFilename: "{app}\simmetrix.ico"
```

`__BUILD__` is defined at the time the program is compiled, and resolves into a date (190128 for today).  That works fine, I get the right directory structure created and my final exe is correctly named.  I'm just trying to now have the icon installed on the desktop contain the same BUILD code, so say SimModeler 7.0-190128 instead of SimModeler 7.0.

I tried even removing the `__BUILD__` and just using SimModeler 7.0-test for DefaultGroupName, but see the same error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe allocate the value to a variable as in the example to this question. Then use the # result for DefaultGroupName. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000979/start-menu-folder-as-a-subdirectory-inno-setup

Comment: You didn't really explain what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to create some icon "group" (as the name of the directive/variable) suggests? Or are you just trying to give a name to one particular shortcut (and if that, why are you trying to do it using a variable, instead of simply using a "hard-coded" name)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl Each build of SimModeler 7.0 has a given build code date, i.e. 7.0-190218.  So instead of an icon on the desktop that just says SimModeler 7.0, I'm trying to create an icon that says SimModeler 7.0-190128 or whatever the given build date is.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle - Thank you!  You pointed me in the right direction, this worked:

#define MyRelease "SimModeler 7.0-\__BUILD\__"

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyRelease}"; Filename: "{app}\simmodeler.bat" ; Comment: "SimModeler"; WorkingDir: "{userdocs}"; IconFilename: "{app}\simmetrix.ico"

Comment: Martin Prikryl it isn't actually a duplicate of the one you linked.  the piece I was missing was that I needed to use a define to get the \__BUILD\__ into a variable.  I incorrectly assumed that a variable created in Setup would be available for use in Icons.  I knew to use the # before the variable, that wasn't my error